# Алгоритм нахождения всех делителей большого числа

Tags: javascript, теория-чисел, факторизация

Мне попалась задача, суть такова: сложить делители числа **n** и сравнить сумму с самим **n**. Но вопрос не про это - вопрос в том, чтобы найти эти делители для огромных чисел, например, для **23_459_879_034**.

```js
function isPerfect(n) {
    let divisors = 0;
    let divisorsSum = 0;

    while (divisors <= n / 2) {
        if (n % divisors === 0) {
            divisorsSum += divisors;
        }

        divisors++;
    }

    return divisorsSum === n;
}

console.log(isPerfect(23459879034));
// true
```

Данный код выполняется очень медленно. Какой алгоритм можно применить, чтобы найти все делители?

Comment: Я поправил метки. Поищите на этом сайте "факторизацию". Их очень много. Число ваше совсем не большое.

Comment: И ещё: сумма делителей отыскивается без поиска самих делителей: [функция делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Comment: Вообще-то совершенных чисел так мало, что проверять смысла нет. Проще сделать табличку :) Даже на [oeis](https://oeis.org/A000396/list) их всего десяток привели...

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то совершенных чисел так мало, что проверять смысла нет. Проще сделать табличку :) Даже на [oeis](https://oeis.org/A000396/list) их всего десяток привели...

Но если ну очень хочется посчитать, я бы начинал с того, что делил на 2, пока делится, считая, сколько раз это удается (пусть k). Потом к тому что осталось, прибавлял бы 1 и опять смотрел — степень ли это двойки? И только если да, причем на одну большая, чем k, вот тогда и только тогда я бы стал выяснять, а не простое ли число 2<sup>k+1</sup>-1.

Потому что все известные ныне совершенные числа имеют вид 2<sup>k-1</sup>(2<sup>k</sup>-1), при этом (2<sup>k</sup>-1) — должно быть простое число.

А что до поиска всех делителей, то, как вам уже советовали, посмотрите [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).